# Unable to get File I/0 working in period counter function -c

Tags: c, file, io

```
int periodCount(const char *filename) {
    FILE * fp;
    int n = 0;

    if( (fp=fopen(filename,"r")) != NULL) {
        while(fgetc(fp)!= EOF) {
            if(fgetc(fp)=='.') n++;
            fclose(fp);
        }
    }   
    return n;
}
```

Here is my code, it simply should count the number of periods in the file named filename, which contains 15 periods, yet when I try to print 'n' at the end of the program, it seems to only be reading 1 of the periods. I know that the problem is probably within the while loop, but I'm not sure why it's doing it.

Answer (score 2):

You're closing the file after the first character. Also you're skipping every other character as a result of not storing the return from `fgetc()`. Change to:

```
int periodCount(const char *filename) {
    FILE * fp;
    int n = 0, c = 0;

    if( (fp=fopen(filename,"r")) != NULL) {
        while( (c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
            if( c == '.' )
                n++;
        }

        fclose(fp);    /*  <---- move this line here  */    
    }   

    return n;
}
```

Comment: also, the first `fgetc` call is not tested for the count.

Comment: @CoryNelson: Yep, just noticed that too.

Answer (score 1):

Your `fclose(fp)` should be outside the `while` loop.

As it is, the code is reading (& discarding) the first character; reading the 2nd character & comparing it to `'.'`; and closing the file.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

1. You have two calls to `fgetc()` but you only test whether one of them returned a dot.
2. You close the file stream in the body of the loop.

You need something more like:

```
if ((fp = fopen(filename,"r")) != NULL)
{
    int c;
    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == '.')
            n++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```